# Magento 1: Cannot update shopping cart

Tags: checkout, magento-1, cart

I have tried to update the core functionality,
`<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>`(after form tag begun)
and also added this too:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost')?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" >
</form>
```

Did the updations in this location:

> /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Comment: have you check log files?

Comment: @Kunj, verified log file's but there is no log record in this location: /var/log/apache2

Comment: check in magento log at magento root  var/log/

Comment: checked and it's empty!

Answer (score 0):

In your Theme

```
/app/design/frontend/yourthemepackage/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml file
```

Or

```
/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml file
```

place on line after getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post"> paste the below code

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Comment: @sanai, made the functionality changes with method: post <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?> but the issue is same.

Comment: Updated this functions also: <form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost')?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" >
</form>